# WordPress Filtering Custom Post Type by Metadata and Search Heirachy

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a custom Post Type called `cptMovie` which has two Custom Field (Metadata) `"Language"` and `"Box office"` assigned to it.

I also have a Custom Taxonomy called `movieTax` with 4 tax Terms "`Action`", "`Comedy`", "`Family`" ,and "`Horror`" .

In a WordPress File structe like below:

1. index.php
2. page.php
3. page-movie.php
4. taxonomy.php
5. taxonomy-movieTax.php

I am able to list and display all the Custom Post Types (movie) under Taxonomy  `(movieTax)` using indexed page `page-movie.php` and custom wp-query and eventually link them to the taxonomy-movieTax.php to have all Post under each tax terms.

Up to here I am Ok and getting the resut BUT I need to add some Filters for users like Filtering the result by Language or Boc office Metadata,

Now my question is Which Part of the WP Template Hierarchy is in charge of displaying the result? Do I have to create the `search.php` if so how a query like this:

```
$arg = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'language',
            'value' => 'english'
        )
    )
);

$filter-lang = new WP_Query( $arg );
```

in `page-movie.php` will end up in search.php?

Thanks,

Comment: I explained earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413110/2311759

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a "search.php" file.

You can add the below code in "page-movie.php" or "taxonomy-movieTax.php" file, as per your requirement.

```
 $arg = array(
          'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
              'key' => 'language',
              'value' => $lang_val,
              'compare' => '='
           ),
           array(
              'key' => 'box_office',
              'value' => $box_office_val,
              'compare' => '='
          )
       )
);

$filter-lang = new WP_Query( $arg );
```

Here, $lang_val & $box_office_val are values to search for language key & box office key respectively. However, if you want to create separate search file, you also need to specify post type in arguments.