# Order wp_query by Vafpress meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to order a custom-post-type WP_Query by a custom [vafpress](http://vafpress.com/documentation/vafpress-framework/getting-started.html) metabox:

My Metabox

```
    $mb = new VP_Metabox(array(
        'id'          => 'meta_person',
        'types'       => array('person'),
        'title'       => __('Person informations', 'dr_domain'),
        'priority'    => 'high',
        'template'    => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'textbox',
                'name' => 'person_name',
                'label' => __('Your Name', 'vp_textdomain'),
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'textbox',
                'name' => 'person_city',
                'label' => __('Your City', 'vp_textdomain'),
            ),

        ),
    ));
```

I want to retrieve Persons by their city, for that here is my Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'person',
    'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_person.person_city',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => 'Paris',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The WP_Query is not returning any result. I tried this option too, with no results:

```
'meta_key' => 'person_city' // No Result
```

So How can I use WP_Query with field and without metabox ID.
Thank you.

Comment: The meta key might be called something slightly different - if you have a look into your database can you find it? I'm unfamiliar with vafpress but it might save it with underscores before it or in the middle of it, eg _person_city or even vaf_person_person_city etc

Comment: In Database: meta_key is meta_person and meta_value is: a:3:{i:0;s:17:"person_name";i:1;s:20:"person_city";i:2;s:20:";}

Comment: try with using relation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413110/2311759 and check your custom post type name and custom field slug. you can check it in `wp_postmeta` table. this has `ID`, `post_id`, `meta_name`, `meta_value`. you should see the `meta_name`. any does not solve ur problem, you may try $wpdp: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb